# Is dcommiting from a rebased branch a good idea?

Tags: git-svn, rebase, dcommit

Consider the following layout:

```
git                 |      svn
-----------------------------------
master              |  trunk
local_experimental  |  experimental
```

Is the following list of command something reasonable to do:

```
git checkout local_experimental
#hack hack hack
#commit changes to experimental svn branch
git svn dcommit experimental

#update the git repository from svn
git checkout master
git svn rebase

git checkout local_experimental
#how will svn handle the two following commands?

#rebase the experimental branch on master to get newest changes
git rebase master
git svn dcommit
```